# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, invalidoperationexception

I have a model called Message. In the model there is a ICollection ResourceSubscribers of another model called Resource. When I try to

```
public void SaveMessage(List<int> subscribers)
    {
        Condition.Requires(model).IsNotNull();
        Message model = new Message();

        //Some assignments to initialize the model

        ICollection<Resource> res = new List<Resource>();

        foreach (var item in subscribers)
        {
            res.Add(this.ResourceService.GetResourceById(item));
        }

        model.ResourceSubscribers = res;
        Context.Messages.Add(model);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

the "Context.Messages.Add(model);" line throws an InvalidOperationException with message "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.".

Answer (score 2):

If you use same Context any where better to use context as singleton instance.

This will Ensure a class has only one instance and provide a global point of access to it

Check this: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx#_self1

Comment: See an answer I got in the past:
`Basically, I would suggest creating a fresh context for each unit of work`   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359297/execution-of-the-command-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connecti

Answer (score 0):

Are you using another context in `GetResourceById` to get the resources? In that case those objects are associated with that context. When doing `Context.Messages.Add` you try to associated the objects with another context which is not allowed.

All related operations that take place together should use the same context. Having multiple contexts around is asking for problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
public void SaveMessage(List<int> subscribers)
    {
        Condition.Requires(model).IsNotNull();
        Message model = new Message();

        //Some assignments to initialize the model

        ICollection<Resource> res = new List<Resource>();

        foreach (var item in subscribers)
        {
                            res.Add(this.Context.Resources.Find(item));
        }

        model.ResourceSubscribers = res;
        Context.Messages.Add(model);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I thought I'd post my answer in case it helps someone.

I came across this same problem in my MVC code, even using the Unit of Work pattern, as mentioned by Elad Benda. I discovered my DbContext resource was not being released at the end of the controller call.

```
    using (_DatabaseUow)
    {
        // your controller code that accesses the database here.
    } // When this goes out of scope dispose is called.
```

Then Dispose the DatabaseUnitOfWork class

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing == true)
        {
            _ObdDbContext.DetachAll();
            _ObdDbContext = null;
            _ObdBusinessData = null;
        }
    }

    ~DatabaseUnitOfWork()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
```

The _ObdBusinessData member is similar to a repository. Finally the DetachAll() method in the DbContext derived class looks like this:

```
    public void DetachAll()
    {
        var entries = SetTestsOnlineData.Local;
        while (entries.Count != 0)
        {
            TestsOnlineData tod = entries[0];
            Tests tro = entries[0].Tests;
            List<TestsDtc> dtcs = entries[0].Tests.TestsDtcs.ToList();

            foreach (TestsDtc dtc in dtcs)
                Detach(dtc);
            Detach(entries[0].Tests);
            Detach(entries[0]);

            tro.TestsDtcs = dtcs;
            tro.TestsOnlineData = tod;
            tod.Tests = tro;
        }
    }

    public void Detach(object entity)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Detach(entity);
    }
```

I used specific knowledge of my entities/objects to detach everything in memory. I have a table called TestsOnlineData. It links to Tests which links to a list of TestsDtc. Notice, I preserve those link relationships since the root of my object tree will be preserved, but the DbContext will release the others when they are detached.

I would have liked to make this more generic, but this worked. I hope this helps.